# Profile/group expiration for non-use?

Tags: 2007, permissions, user-profile, expiration

I am wondering if it is possible to be notified if a Sharepoint user and/or group has not been used in a specified amount of time. For example, if user - "Bob" does not log into our sharepoint site in 30 days a notification will be sent out. Also, if there is a sharepoint permission group - "SubSiteSuper" whose users do not access the site/list/item of which "SubSiteSuper" has permissions on in 30 days a notification goes out.

My main goal here is to be able to manage unused permissions groups and its users so that they can be manually or automatically deleted. If anyone has heard of something like this via a custom workflow or third party application please help!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to achieve what you want to do,

I find few links that will definitely gonna help you

http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/programmatically-get-last-login-time-11376.aspx

and

http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/users-not-logged-sharepoint-403.aspx

Now one of links says you can get list of users from top level site collection and then check there last login time, but I would suggest if you can add a user property that is setup in a way that when user log ins it will save an entry of user name, url and date time for that specific user to Database and then create another timer job that will check that table everyday to see if any of user passed 30 days period, I am pretty sure yu will easily find coding for these problems but if you couldn't I will find you some.

Hope it helps :D